# No implicit Ordering defined for org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm playing around with Spark in Scala and a dataset with a predefined Schema I've developed.

The problem I'm facing is when I try to sortBy the current RDD by a field whose type is TimestampType, as the following message appears in the log.

```
No implicit Ordering defined for org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType.
```

For the given lines of code.

```
.sortBy(event => event
      .getAs("sample.timestamp")
      .asInstanceOf[TimestampType],
      ascending = true,
      1)
```

Comment: did you try with import `df.orderBy(asc("timestamp"))`

Comment: @ShankarKoirala thanks for the reply! Made a mistake in the description and I'm working with a RDD and not a DF. I saw a couple of answers talking about .orderBy but it's impossible to apply it now.

Answer (score 2):

`TimestampType` is not the actual type of values in the column. It defines the data type at the *schema* level (in `StructType` -> `StructField`s), but the undelying values type should be `java.sql.Timestamp`.

If you cast the value to `Timestamp`, the ordering should work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already tried with that and got the same error.

Comment: Could you please show how the schema is defined for your RDD?